# How to hide column header from the result set output?

Tags: sql

I have a piece of SQL query which returns the result set with `email_address` column name on the top row like this:

```
|   email_adress    |
|-------------------|
| test@gmail.com    |
| test123@gmail.com |
```

What I need instead a result set without the first row like:

```
| test@gmail.com    |
| test123@gmail.com |
```

Here's my query:

```
SELECT email_address
FROM company_digital
WHERE email_address IS NOT NULL
AND email_address IS NOT NULL
AND hash_id >= 700
AND hash_id < 800
UNION
SELECT email_address_2
FROM company_digital
WHERE email_address_2 IS NOT NULL
AND email_address_2 IS NOT NULL
AND hash_id >= 700
AND hash_id < 800
UNION
SELECT email_address_3
FROM company_digital
WHERE email_address_3 IS NOT NULL
AND email_address_3 IS NOT NULL
AND hash_id >= 700
AND hash_id < 800;
```

Comment: You want to skip the first result row or just display the results without a column header?

Comment: Yes, Column header

Comment: This isnt a sql language issue. It would depend on specifically which SQL client you're using to run your queries. Which one is it? You should consider adding that tag to your question.

Comment: Are you extracting this data?  What is the reason you don't want the column header to return?  It will always return if you're running a query in something like Management Studio.

Comment: You should update the question with the information of what DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your mean the column header then give the first field in the query an alias like:

```
select email_address AS Whatever
from company_digital
where email_address is not null
and email_address is not null
and hash_id >=700 and hash_id <800
union
select email_address_2
from company_digital
where email_address_2 is not null
and email_address_2 is not null
and hash_id >=700 and hash_id <800
union
select email_address_3
from company_digital
where email_address_3 is not null
and email_address_3 is not null
and hash_id >=700 and hash_id <800;
```

Which would output:

```
| Whatever |
_____________
test@gmail.com

test123@gmail.com
_________________
```

Or

```
select email_address AS ' '
from company_digital
where email_address is not null
and email_address is not null
and hash_id >=700 and hash_id <800
union
select email_address_2
from company_digital
where email_address_2 is not null
and email_address_2 is not null
and hash_id >=700 and hash_id <800
union
select email_address_3
from company_digital
where email_address_3 is not null
and email_address_3 is not null
and hash_id >=700 and hash_id <800;
```

Which would output:

```
|  |
_____________
test@gmail.com

test123@gmail.com
_________________
```

EDIT CLEAN UP CODE:

```
SELECT email_address AS ' '
FROM company_digital
WHERE email_address IS NOT NULL
AND hash_id BETWEEN 700 AND 800
UNION
SELECT email_address_2
FROM company_digital
WHERE email_address_2 IS NOT NULL
AND hash_id BETWEEN 700 AND 800
UNION
SELECT email_address_3
FROM company_digital
WHERE email_address_3 IS NOT NULL
AND hash_id BETWEEN 700 AND 800;
```

Or depending on your data...

```
SELECT CASE WHEN email_address IS NOT NULL 
            THEN email_address
            WHEN email_address_2 IS NOT NULL 
            THEN email_address_2 
            WHEN email_address_3 IS NOT NULL 
            THEN email_address_3
       END AS ' '
FROM company_digital
WHERE hash_id BETWEEN 700 AND 800
```

Comment: The header vertical bars and dashes still exist, so I don't see how your answer suppress the column header.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not what the OP would want but still posting this for community. You can also do a cast, like this:

```
select CAST(email_address as nvarchar)
```

even though email_address is already an nvarchar, this works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SET FMTONLY ON;
SELECT email_address
FROM company_digital
WHERE email_address IS NOT NULL
AND email_address IS NOT NULL
AND hash_id >= 700
AND hash_id < 800
UNION
SELECT email_address_2
FROM company_digital
WHERE email_address_2 IS NOT NULL
AND email_address_2 IS NOT NULL
AND hash_id >= 700
AND hash_id < 800
UNION
SELECT email_address_3
FROM company_digital
WHERE email_address_3 IS NOT NULL
AND email_address_3 IS NOT NULL
AND hash_id >= 700
AND hash_id < 800;

SET FMTONLY OFF;
```

Comment: That suppresses **all** output!!